# Table of Descriptions

Tags: table-of-contents, description

I'd like to display a list of descriptions, similar to a TOC, LOF or LOT. How would I do this? Maybe using the `tocloft`-package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by `description`s. For LaTeX, a `description` list is something quite well defined. Are you using the term `description` in this LaTeX sense? If not, please tell us what you have in mind.

Comment: What do you mean with descriptions? Maybe you mean nomeclature?

Comment: Sorry for being ambiguous (my hope was to be clear due to the `description`-tag). Indeed, what I mean with `description` is the list-type environment á la: `\begin{description}…\end{description}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous- I have interpreted `description` to mean the default list-type `environment`. If this is not appropriate, please update your question with *a lot* more detail, although you should be able to adapt my solution.

[image: screenshot]

- I have used the command `\@starttoc` to start a file called `\jobname.dsc` that will contain the entries.
- I have used the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) to provide a new key for the `description` environment (which will actually work for any other list-type environment, too) which can be used in the form

  `\begin{description}[tocentry={another description}]`

  which you can obviously put whatever you like in.

Here's a complete MWE (compile twice):

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% this sets up \jobname.dsc which will store the 
% contentslines added on each descriptions
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listdescriptionname{List of descriptions}
\newcommand\listofdescriptions{%
  \section*{\listdescriptionname}\@starttoc{dsc}}
\makeatother

\SetEnumitemKey{tocentry}{before=\addcontentsline{dsc}{section}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\listofdescriptions

\section{Main document}
\begin{description}[tocentry={for the toc}]
\item first
\item second
\end{description}

\begin{description}[tocentry={another description}]
\item first
\item second
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add every label of an item (every item has one, like `\item[label] text`) to the `\listofdescriptions`?

Comment: @idle yes, probably- please update your question with a lot more details; perhaps you could give a small sample document and illustrate the desired output